# Ruby initialization idiom using symbols

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some work in an existing Ruby code base, and I'm quite new to Ruby. I see this initialization idiom pretty often:

```
def initialize(input)
    @number         = input[:number]
    @color          = input[:color]
  end
```

I guess I have two questions. One is whether this is a common idiom and if so, what's good about it? The second is, what is actually happening here? Is the implication that input is an array? A hash? The underlying mechanics aren't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's common.  Generally when you see code like this, it means that `input` is a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html).  Occasionally someone might pass in an object that acts like a hash, though, and we can still expect this code to work.  We can tell that `input` is definitely not an array, because arrays require Integers to be used as their index, but `:number` and `:color` are Symbols.

Whenever you see something starting with a colon like `:number`, that is a [Ruby symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-/Symbol.html).

Whenever you see something starting with a `@` like `@number`, that is the name of an instance variable.  Instance variables are used to store data inside objects for later use.

Suppose we have a class `Foo` defined like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(input)
    @number = input[:number]
    @color = input[:color]
  end
end
```

In this case, we can create a new object like this:

```
Foo.new(number: 4, color: 'red')
```

The code above is equivalent to:

```
input_hash = { :number => 4, :color => 'red' }
Foo.new(input_hash)
```

One nice thing about this pattern is that you can tell exactly what each input variable is being used for because it will be written next to a descriptive symbol, and also it doesn't matter what order you put the input variables in.

### Improvements

If you want to improve this code, you might consider using a new feature of Ruby called [keyword arguments](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).  Alternatively, you might also consider [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) so you can have more control over what happens when one of the keys is missing, instead of just storing a nil value in your object.  I would also recommend that you check the input hash for any unexpected keys and raise an exception if they are found.

Comment: Another advantage is that using a single hash as an argument (instead of multiple primitives) allows you to change the hash without changing the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a common idiom and if so, what's good about it?

It's not common, but it's acceptable. When there are more than n parameters being passed in, where "n" is often > 3, we should use a hash.

What's good about it? Look at the code. Is it simple and readable? Does it make sense that an input parameter of `:number` is being assigned to an instance variable of the same name?

> what is actually happening here? Is the implication that input is an array? A hash? The underlying mechanics aren't clear to me.

It's a hash where `:number` and `:color` are keys.